# how to set value of text input using jQuery so that it's added to the html in the form?

Tags: jquery, class, input

I have a form in my sidebar that is part of a Wordpress plugin and I'm not sure where the PHP code that generates the form resides, so I'd like to add a class and a value to the text input using jQuery.  So far I have:

```
$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('form#searchform').find(':input#s').addClass('default-value');
    $j('form#searchform').find(':input#s').val('enter search here...');
});
```

The class is added successfully to the html, but though the value shows in the text input, it is not added to the html, i.e. within the  tag, which needs to happen for my default value script to work.  So, I'm wondering if there is a way of adding the value inline?

**DEFAULT VALUE SCRIPT**

```
  $j('.default-value').each(function() {
      var default_value = $j(this).val();
      $j(this).css('color', '#837D73'); // this could be in the style sheet instead
      $j(this).focus(function() {
          if(this.value == default_value) {
              this.value = '';
              $j(this).css('color', 'black');
          }
      });
      $j(this).blur(function() {
          if(this.value == '') {
              $j(this).css('color', '#837D73');
              this.value = default_value;
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can't you use `$j('#s')` instead of `$j('form#searchform').find(':input#s')`? You shouldn't have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: What do you mean "within the tag?"

Comment: when you say it's not added to the html, do you mean when you view source, or if you inspect the element?

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  Yes, `$j('#s')` works as well.  I mean when I inspect the element it is not showing the value as set there.  There was an answer below with `$j('#s').attr('value', 'enter search here...');` which does now set the value inline.  Not sure why it was removed.

Comment: .attr('value', 'enter search here...') is just the same with .val('...')

Comment: Over-specifying ids is not necessary since ids like **nnnnnn** said, must be unique. So `form#searchform` and `input#s` are being over-specified.

Comment: @fedmich `.attr('value', 'enter search here...')` adds the value inline to the html for the input text box, i.e. `<input type="text" value="enter search here...">` whereas `.val('...')` doesn't.  Having said this neither method is working with my default value script, when on all other inputs on the page all I need to do is to set the value and add the class "default-value" and it works.  I'll add the default value script to the question.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, yeah they are different alright. but I just meant he could just use the .val() for his basic usage

Comment: I have just worked out that wrapping the default value script in a `$j('body').ready(function() {` was the issue.  As I was setting the value and class using jQuery, I needed to add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be working. Just make sure you add the class name
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/NbRBe/

and notice the

```
var default_value = this.value; //<-do it like this instead
```

Tip: you should try to use jquery chaining

You could simplify your code like this.

```
$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('input#s')
        .addClass('default-value')
        .val('enter search here...');
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can only see the html when I inspect the elements as the form is generated by a PHP script, and I'm not sure how to copy the html.  You can see the form in action at the top of the sidebar on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/)

Comment: Ah I see what you're trying to do, "input placeholder", let me ammend my code then.

Comment: I have just worked out that wrapping the default value script in a `$j('body').ready(function() {` was the issue.  As I was setting the value and class using jQuery, I needed to add this.  Both methods, i.e. `.attr('value', 'enter search here...')` and `.val();` now work.